# how select all existing fields in a collection from an field of type object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection that have a field named "data" that can have any fields, and I have to get all existing fields in all collections in that "data" field or get the documents that have diferents fields in that "data" field.

for example, if I have:

```
[
    {
        _id: "45454",
        name: "fulano",
        city: "cali",
        data: {
            age: 12,
            lastName: "panguano",
            cars: 0
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "67899",
        name: "juanito",
        city: "cali",
        data: {
            age: 23,
            lastName: "merlano",
            cars: 2
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "67899",
        name: "olito",
        city: "nw",
        data: {
            lastName: "betito",
            cars: 2
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "11223",
        name: "cabrito",
        city: "trujillo",
        data: {
            age: 28,
            cars: 1,
            moto: 3
        }
    },
]
```

what I would like to get:

```
["age", "lastName", "cars", "moto"]
```

**or** :

> documents where the "data" fields vary, regardless of their values.

```
[
    {
        _id: "45454",
        name: "fulano",
        city: "cali",
        data: {
            age: 12,
            lastName: "panguano",
            cars: 0
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "67899",
        name: "olito",
        city: "nw",
        data: {
            lastName: "betito",
            cars: 2
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "11223",
        name: "cabrito",
        city: "trujillo",
        data: {
            age: 28,
            cars: 1,
            moto: 3
        }
    }
    
]
```

> THE COLLECTION HAVE SO MANY DOCUMENTS CAN BE A PROBLEM IF I USE
> FINDALL AND THEN USE A LOOP LIKE FOR (FOR THE RESOURCES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless how you execute this (in memory or on the db) this is a very expensive query, with that said I agree doing this in memory is the wrong approach.

Here's how to do it using the aggregation pipeline and some standard operators like `$map` and `$objectToArray`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      keys: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$data"
          },
          in: "$$this.k"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$keys"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$keys"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AtXGrwvzRYW)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using javascript once you have an array of all documents in the collection:

```
let arr = [
    {
        _id: "45454",
        name: "fulano",
        city: "cali",
        data: {
            age: 12,
            lastName: "panguano",
            cars: 0
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "67899",
        name: "juanito",
        city: "cali",
        data: {
            age: 23,
            lastName: "merlano",
            cars: 2
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "67899",
        name: "olito",
        city: "nw",
        data: {
            lastName: "betito",
            cars: 2
        }
    },
    {
        _id: "11223",
        name: "cabrito",
        city: "trujillo",
        data: {
            age: 28,
            cars: 1,
            moto: 3
        }
    },
]
```

You can use the .map method to get an array of the data objects like so:

```
arr = arr.map(obj => obj.data)
```

This will return

```
[
    {
        "age": 12,
        "lastName": "panguano",
        "cars": 0
    },
    {
        "age": 23,
        "lastName": "merlano",
        "cars": 2
    },
    {
        "lastName": "betito",
        "cars": 2
    },
    {
        "age": 28,
        "cars": 1,
        "moto": 3
    }
]
```

Then you can get an array of data object keys by looping through the array of data objects like so:

```
let dataKeys = [];
arr.forEach(obj => {
        dataKeys = [...dataKeys, ...Object.keys(obj)]
    })
```

This returns an array of non unique keys:

```
dataKeys = [
    "age",
    "lastName",
    "cars",
    "age",
    "lastName",
    "cars",
    "lastName",
    "cars",
    "age",
    "cars",
    "moto"
]
```

Then filter out the unique keys using .filter and .findIndex methods:

```
let uniqueKeys = dataKeys.filter((elem, index) => dataKeys.findIndex(obj => obj === elem) === index)
```

And this will give you

```
[
    "age",
    "lastName",
    "cars",
    "moto"
]
```

Comment: The problem is that the collection has many documents and using a find and then using a for can consume a lot of resources, wouldn't it?